# Add Facebook friends to Website [Graph API 2.5]

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-invite

I'm developing a website where users can add their facebook friends. Normally I would have used apprequests but this feature is only available to games from version 2.3 onwards.Currently I'm just able to use [send request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) feature of Graph API to send messages to friends but I also want to retrieve the list of friends to whom message was sent.

**Javascript SDK code**..

```
       function importfb(){

        FB.login(function(response) {
            // handle the response
            console.log("Response goes here!");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

            // check whether user is logged in or not and ask for credentials if not.
            FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,locale,gender', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name+" "+response.id+" "+response.email);
                loginpassword = response.id;
                loginemail =  response.email;
            });

            // retrieve the list of friends to whom message was sent
            FB.api("/me/friends?fields=id,name,email", function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    /* handle the result */
                    console.log("Response goes here!");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                    console.log('Successful info for: ' + response.name+" "+response.id+" "+response.email);
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                }
                }
            );

            // send message to facebook friends using send request dialog
            FB.ui({
                method: 'send',
                link: 'http://www.google.com/',
            });

        }, {scope: 'email,public_profile,user_friends'});

    }
```

Using the above code I'm able to send messages to facebook friends but not able to retrieve the list of friends to whom message was sent. Please Help..

**EDIT 1**:

I'm trying to separately print the entire friend list in the console using the 2nd FB.api function but as now this is all I'm able to print..

```
   Response goes here!
   {"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":147}}
   Successful info for: undefined undefined undefined
```

Any idea how to print the data array inside the response?? Because even *response.data[0]* is not printing anything.

Comment: may i ask, what for do you want to know which friends got the message?

Comment: So that when that friends signs up to my website I can send a notification that your friend has joined

Comment: check out the last paragraph of my answer about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the docs, there is no response data from using the Send Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

There is no way to get the information which friends did get the message.

Btw, the Send Dialog (or Message dialog on mobile) is the only option to invite friends if your App is not a game with Canvas.

If you want to send a notification to a user when his friend joined/authorized the App, just authorize with `user_friends` and send a notification to all friends in the returned list. After all, you only get those friends who authorized your App already. You don´t need to store invited friends for that.

Comment: I'm using "user_friends" permission in my 2nd FB.api function to get friend list separately but not able to print the friendlist in console. Any idea what's wrong with that function?

Comment: what means "not able"? what is the exact response of your api call?

Comment: I have edited my question to display the api response in console.

Comment: looks good to me. what else do you expect to get? the call was successful as it seems, because there is the total friend count. and it seems that no friend authorized your app with the user_friends permission, so the list is empty.

Comment: read the last part of my answer, you ONLY get friends who authorized your app with /me/friends anyway, so you can just use that list to send notifications whenever someone new authorizes the app.

Comment: Ok...So what do I need to use to get the entire friend list irrespective of whether they have authorized my app or not?

Comment: why would you need the entire friend list? what for? you want to notify existing users if their friends joined the app, right? and inviting with the send dialog does not require you to get access to the friends, the user can select the recipients in the dialog.

Comment: I need the entire list of user A so that when a user's friend B signs up in my website I can search B's id in the friend list of A and if a match is found send him a notification. Any ideas how to implement this?

Comment: i am not sure how else to explain this, but you do NOT need the entire list of friends. you ONLY need the list of friends who authorized your app, and that´s exactly what you will get with /me/friends.

Comment: read the last paragraph of my answer carefully, it explains exactly what you need to do. user B signs up, you get his friends with /me/friends, you will only get authorized users so you just send a notification to everyone you get with /me/friends. that´s it.

Comment: Understood..Does "user_friends" feature works for test apps as well or just live apps? because currently my app is a test app and when one of my facebook friends who is a tester for this test app signed up using his Facebook credentials the output of data array was still empty as mentioned in the edit above.

Comment: if 2 friends both authorize an app with user_friends, you will get them with the api call. it must be the exact same app, of course, and it does not matter if it´s a test app or a real one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103068/discussion-between-lucy-and-luschn).

Comment: It finally worked after clearing the cache in my browser so that the new JS code in the webpage could get loaded.. Thanks a lot for your help!!